# Invalid Token in xmldoc.selectnodes if string contains a dot

Tags: xml, vb.net, search, selectnodes

I'm searching for a string in a XML file. The string has a dot in it, and causes a invalid token error to appear.

```
 For Each d As XmlNode In xmlDoc2.SelectNodes("//*[@ StructType = '" & r.Item(2).ToString & "'")

r.Item(2).ToString = CX8090_QA.Publishing.Errors
```

I would like to search for this string just as it is, and have the ' in place too. But it doesn't seem to take it as a string.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted, your XPath expression is missing closing square bracket :

```
xmlDoc2.SelectNodes("//*[@StructType = '" & r.Item(2).ToString & "']")
```

Other than that it should be fine as long as the dynamic string part of the XPath doesn't contain single-quote, which will conflict string-literal delimiter being used.

Comment: thank you.. didnt see it in two days. that was indeed the problem.